# WWW Resolve .htaccess Showing index.php in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So im using .htaccess to resolve all non-www requests to the www. domain, but the code im using produces a url which always shows index.php even from direct requests i.e. typing example.co.uk --> loads www.example.co.uk/index.php.

Heres the code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


AddHandler php55-script .php .php5

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#2 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /index.html http://site.co.uk/index.php

#3 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /lizards.html http://site.co.uk/stocklist/lizards.php

#4 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /snakes.html http://site.co.uk/stocklist/snakes.php

#5 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /amphibians.html http://site.co.uk/stocklist/amphibians.php

#6 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /misc.html http://site.co.uk/stocklist/misc.php

#7 Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /tortoisesandturtles.html    http://site.co.uk/stocklist/tortoisesandturtles.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to keep this `www` rule before your other rules.

Alternatively you can modify this rule a bit:

```
# for index.php OR home
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://www.reptilesplus.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

# for rest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.reptilesplus.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Im getting a redirect loop with both answers. Is there an apache setting that redirects to reptilesplus.co.uk/index.php which could be causing these loops?

Comment: Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess OR is there any CMS/PHP framework running there? Can you try to run this in a different browser to avoid 301 caching?

Comment: only a few 301's for redirecting old pages to the new ones, nothing that should interfere with this rule. Did think to try in a different browser - tried FF, chrome and IE, same problem. I have a feeling it may be something in the server config files but its a shared hosting so not sure whether i'll be able to make any changes...

Comment: ok, can you place your latest & full .htaccess in your question so that I can investigate and suggest accordingly.

Comment: Ok problem is probably this line: `Redirect 301 /index.html http://reptilesplus.co.uk/index.php` comment it out and test after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Argh! forehead slap moment. i must've had code blindness - works fine now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible by adding `index\.php` to a part of the first argument that isn't being copied over to the url. You can make it optional by using `?`, which makes the previous character/group match either 0 or 1 times. We can use the `[OR]` flag to check if either the url doesn't start with www. or index.php is present in the url.

The following (untested) code should do the trick

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.reptilesplus\.co\.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/?)?(.*)$ http://www.reptilesplus.co.uk/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This *should* happen:

```
http://example.com/index.php/1       --> http://www.example.com/1
http://example.com/1                 --> http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/index.php/1   --> http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/1             --> Doesn't match
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately it results in a redirect loop. When reloaded the url alternates between www.reptilesplus.co.uk and reptilesplus.co.uk/index.php.

Any idea?

Comment: This rule alone doesn't make that happen. There might be an other rule active, either in .htaccess or in the server configuration file.